# console.trace() method giving different outputs in synchronous and asynchronous closed function calls

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, stack-trace

First code-snippet:

```js
console.log("First")

function main() { 
    var n = 10;
    
    function nested(argument) {

        console.log(n);
        console.trace();
    }

    setTimeout(nested, 0);

    console.trace();
    console.log("Last command inside nested function");   
}

main();

console.trace();

console.log("Last");
```

[Output of first code-snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQjVG.png)

Here, `nested` is being asynchronously called after `Last` has been logged.

The `console.trace()` command shows that all the functions are in the execution stack, including the function `main`, in which `nested` is declared.

I was guessing this was because even though the execution context of `main` had been popped from the execution stack, `nested` still had access to its lexical environment which is why it showed all the functions.

Second code-snippet:

```js
console.log("First")

function main() { 
    var n = 10;
    
    function nested(argument) {

        console.log(n);
        console.trace();
    }
    console.trace();

    console.log("Last command inside main function");   
    return nested;

}

var hello = main();

hello();

console.log("Last");
```

[Output of second code-snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLVhr.png)

In this, `nested` is being synchronously called, after it is returned from the function `main`.  In this case, only `nested` and the global anonymous function are shown to be in the execution stack.

Why is that? Shouldn't the second one also show all the functions to be in the execution stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The console.trace() command shows that all the functions are in the execution stack

They're not.

The dev-tools of your browser do keep track of the initial call stack, and then rebuild it for your convenience when you call `console.trace()`, or get an `Error` instance's `.stack`. But the initial function is not on the stack anymore.
Not all browsers do keep that *async* trace, for instance Safari doesn't and there the trace will start at `nested` in your first example. Which is actually correct, but not very useful for debugging.
You can see in your trace that your browser (Chrome) does actually explicitly mark where the "real" stack ended, by marking the previous entry with an `(async)` suffix. Firefox has a similar mark in their trace.

It becomes even more mind blowing when you start dealing with `async` functions, because after the engine meets an `await` clause, everything that happened before, even if it's technically in the same function, is not on the stack anymore. Once again, if you can you may want to check how Safari reports it, since they actually do expose internal methods:

```js
async function foo() {
  await null;
  console.trace();
}
foo();
```

Outputs

> ```
> Trace
>   (anonymous function) (js:3)
>   asyncFunctionResume
>   (anonymous function)
>   promiseReactionJobWithoutPromise
> ```

Where you can see that both `foo` and the *Global Code* have been lost.

If you wish, you can read more about this async-trace feature in this V8-dev article: https://docs.google.com/document/d/13Sy_kBIJGP0XT34V1CV3nkWya4TwYx9L3Yv45LdGB6Q/edit

> I was guessing this was because even though the execution context of `main` had been popped from the execution stack, `nested` still had access to its lexical environment which is why it showed all the functions.

As you may now better understand, that's not the reason, no. It's shown because your browser thinks that if you need the trace it's more because you want to know where the call came from **in your code**, rather than what was really on the internal call stack. After all the goal is to be useful to the developers.

> In this case, only `nested` and the global anonymous function are shown to be in the execution stack.

Because they're only what remains on the call stack. The call to `nested` is made from the global (anonymous) context that's being created by the `<script>` tag execution, `main` has been executed to completion and removed from the stack, everything is as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't the second one also show all the functions to be in the execution stack?

No. In the first example, as the trace shows, toplevel called `main`, which called `setTimeout`, which caused the execution of `nested`.

In the second example, toplevel called `main`, and then toplevel called `hello`. The fact that `hello` was constructed inside of `main` (and that it closes over some of its variables) has nothing to do with the execution stack.

The reason has nothing to do with synchronous or asynchronous:

```js
function a(val) {
  function b() {
    console.trace(val);
  }
  b();
}

const c = a(42);  // toplevel calls a, a calls b
```

```js
function a(val) {
  return function b() {
    console.trace(val);
  }
}

const c = a(42);  // toplevel calls a
c();              // toplevel calls b (a.k.a. c)
```

In both cases, `b` closes over `val`, and in both cases there is no asynchronicity at all, but the results parallel your examples. This is because stack doesn't care where your values are defined. As far as the execution stack is concerned, it does not matter if `a` returns function `b`, or the number `42`. The fact that `b` remembers `val` is similarly irrelevant.

The only thing that the execution stack cares about is, when function `b` is executed, which function's execution caused it. In your second example, `hello` is the result created by `main`, but its execution is caused by toplevel, not `main`.

Comment: Could you explain the logic behind the `(anonymous)` function at the bottom of the execution stack? 

Is it because the whole Javascript file placed inside an anonymous function?

Comment: Also, what is the significance of passing `val` into the `console.trace()` method?

Comment: Yes, the toplevel is basically an unnamed function, AFAIK. There is no significance to passing `val` except to show a parallel to the closure over `n` in your own code.