# details of console.trace() with async events

Tags: javascript, settimeout

recursive setTimeout(), with console.trace() suggests growing call-stack

I've added a console.trace() within a recursive setTimeout() and it suggests a growing call stack.
Is console.trace() showing more than the call stack?
Here is my sample recursive setTimeout..

```
export function loop()
{
    console.log(' start loop');
    let myPromise = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>
    {
        if (window.counter > 100)
        {
            return;
        }
        window.counter = window.counter+1;
        console.log(' counter:' + window.counter);
        console.log('--trace start--');
        console.trace();
        console.log('--trace end--');
        setTimeout(()=>
        {
            console.log('timeout expired');
            resolve("done");
            console.log('return from resolve.')
        },500);
    });
    console.log(' created promise');
    console.log(' resolving promise then');
    myPromise.then((msg)=>
    {
        console.log(' next timeout');
        loop();
        console.log(' return from loop 1')
    })

}
```

Here is the index.html to go with the above 'loop.js'

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>
<h3> Test </h3>

<script type="module">
    import {loop} from "./loop.js"
    window.addEventListener('load',(e)=>
    {
        window.counter=0;
        console.log(' initial load');
        loop();
    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here is the index.html to use to go with the above loop.js

Comment: I ran your code in Firefox, it went through all the 100 iterations. What exactly is the problem you're having ?

Comment: Does the call stack truly grow with each timeout as suggested by the growing report from console.trace()?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the case below explains how stack.trace() reports a 'trail' of calls including records from async event calls.  So the recursive setTimeout() does not create ever-growing call stacks.

[Stack Overflow][console.trace() method giving different outputs in synchronous and asynchronous closed function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73725546/console-trace-method-giving-different-outputs-in-synchronous-and-asynchronous)